# Returning Data Base on Dropdown Value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a sheet where it will automatically fill out columns based on their role.

I have here Sheet 1, the dump where players' name will be placed and a dropdown of their roles.

[image: Roles]

On another sheet (Sheet 2), I have 2 columns, of which I need to sort if they are a player (Rank 1 to Rank 5) or a setter.

[image: Sheet 2]

I am trying to return the values of 'Name' to its respective column on Sheet 2. I tried using arrayformula with ifs but it just returns false. Is there a way for me to do this?

Here's a sample file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qkk9a3r3xJbRgqJfKQKGN8vSrAUz259D5ICuf4bAAaU/edit#gid=1063674487

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Use `Filter()` with `Sort()` formula.

Comment: here with the desired output :) : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qkk9a3r3xJbRgqJfKQKGN8vSrAUz259D5ICuf4bAAaU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Harun24hr sort with filter doesn't return the desired output. it overwrites column 2 with the name's role.

Comment: >I am trying to return the values of 'Name' to its respective column on Sheet 2

There is no such tab name as "Sheet 2"

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

Filter  by `Rank` or `Setter`:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A10, Sheet1!B2:B10="Setter")
```

For rank, try `<>Setter`